# How to send access token to server the most safest way with GET request?

Tags: javascript, security, oauth-2.0, access-token

I need to send access_token to my REST server...

1. How to send access token to server with GET request?
2. Is it safe to make request like: https://localhost:8443/docs/1?access_token=12345 ? I am using HTTPS.

Comment: the querystring is encrypted by https

Comment: @dandavis thanks. So is it safe to do it this way? You can also see the request (and url with that token) in browser

Comment: Probably better to send it as a header rather than a query

Comment: Do not send access tokens in the query string. Query strings are often logged which discloses the token. The risk is limited but still exists. Only send privileged information in HTTP headers over encrypted (HTTPS) connections.

Comment: you can always see the token from the browser, no matter what part of the req/res you tuck it in...

Answer (score 0):

As per the OAuth 2.0 standards, it is recommended to pass the Access Token as a bearer header.

Please check [RFC 6759](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-48) for more information.